# Pushed ViewController from Container ViewController Cut Off in Storyboard

Tags: swift, storyboard, uicontainerview

I have a container `viewcontroller` that pushes another `viewcontroller` onto the navigation stack that begins and is embedded at the parent `viewcontroller` hosting the container `viewcontroller`.

The pushed `viewcontroller` should/does cover the entire screen, but I don't have the same working space available in `storyboard` where the pushed `viewcontroller's` screen is cut off to the dimensions of the container `viewcontroller`.

Any appropriate ways to configure `storyboard` to accommodate?

Comment: Possible, you need to change the simulated size in the Size Inspector, from Fixed to Freeform ?

Comment: yes that worked!

Comment: Thanks, I've updated that as the answer then.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the simulated size in the Size Inspector from Fixed to Freeform

[image]